# Fiscal year and month parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm working on a report that reports on a month that a user can select from a drop-down and also reports on the cumulative data for the fiscal year up until the month selected.

How would I go about setting up the parameters so that they can select this fiscal year first from the drop-down and then the second drop-down list with automatically populate which months in that fiscal year has completed or is currently in?

For example, I choose '2019' for my fiscal year, the month date should only show the following choices: October, November, December.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will find that you will have a better experience if you
take moment to take the [Stack Overflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You can
also read about asking a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
If you follow the norms of the Stack Overflow community and approach it with an
attitude of helping others too, it will serve you well.

Comment: what your looking for is CASCADING parameters. You will need to create 2 datasets. 1st one for year and a 2nd one for months. ds_months will take year as a parameter. Finally on sql side of your ds_month you will have to get top 4 and order by desc. and then take ranks 2, 3, 4 (as you want last 3 months)

Answer (score 1):

You may create table with such fields: Year, Month. Run such code

```
select distinct Year from table order by Year desc
```

to select all fiscal years.
Add change event listener to drop-down (fiscal years), on fire run such code:

```
select Month from table where Year = @year
```

to select months (@year - chosen fiscal year)